# Random Percent in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I want there to be a 50% chance of getting a number. Example: A character has 100 Damage but will have about 50% that deals 200 Damage. It is similar to the critical rate in the League of Legends.

Comment: Please improve the problem description.

Comment: **if (Math.random() > 0.5)**

Comment: Example: A character, each attack will usually deal 100 damage but will have 50% to inflict 200 damage. Ie: in 100 attacks there will be 50 times 100 Damage and 50 times 200 Damage. I'm from Vietnam so I'm not good at English. Wish you sympathize.

Answer (score 1):

I added a variable instead of just simply declaring if (Math.random()), so you can see WHERE the critical chance is happening, the variable is not necessary

```
var critchance:Number = 0;    

saidcharacterHP-=100;
critchance = Math.random();
if (critchance>0.5)
{
  saidcharacterHP-=100;
}
```